# Is it possible to use Rust's log info for tests?

Tags: rust

I have some tests which use `info!` from Rust's log crate. I tried:

```
RUST_LOG=all cargo test -- --nocapture my_tests
```

but the logs simply won't come out.

I didn't init the logger though, because puttin `env_logger::init();` won't work:

```
failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `env_logger`
```

Comment: You need to init the logger if you want the tests to be printed. If `env_logger` doesn't work, perhaps you're missing the requisite line in `Cargo.toml`, under dev-dependencies?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may try to use one of several workarounds.

First is to use `println` when crate is compiled for test like this.

```rust
#[cfg(not(test))] 
use log::{info, warn}; // Use log crate when building application
 
#[cfg(test)]
use std::{println as info, println as warn}; // Workaround to use prinltn! for logs.
```

To prevent `cargo` from silencing tests stdout, run tests like this

```
$ cargo test -- --nocapture
```

Another elegant workaround is to use [test-log](https://crates.io/crates/test-log) crate

```
#[test_log::test] // Automatically wraps test to initialize logging
fn hello_log_tests() {
  // ...
}
```

To use dependency (such as `env_logger` mentioned in error message) for tests include it in `dev-dependencies` section

```
[dev-dependencies]
env_logger = "*"
```

Comment: I like the first solution very much, but `info!` sometimes have 3 parameters, the first one being a target. Is it possible to simulate this too?

Comment: You seem like you know more about logging within Rust tests than most people. I'd love if you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73293801/470749 Thanks!

Comment: @Inline [test-env-log](https://crates.io/crates/test-env-log) was renamed in [test-log](https://crates.io/crates/test-log) by its author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your Rust test function to set up logging using `env_logger`, log some information, and run tests with `RUST_LOG=info cargo test -- --nocapture`:

```rust
 
use log::info;

#[test]
fn test_something() {
    // Initialize the logger for tests
    // Both of the following lines are functionally equivalent, and the choice is a matter of preference:
    // Method 1: Using try_init() directly
    let _ = env_logger::try_init();

    // Method 2: Using builder() with is_test(true) and then try_init()
    // let _ = env_logger::builder().is_test(true).try_init();

    // Log some information
    info!("==== some info"); 
}
```

`RUST_LOG=all` have no effect.