# Creating a proxy function for a Rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

I'm following this workaround to get info!, log! etc working on tests:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67105052/5884503

This is what I did. I created proxy functions to be imported just in the case we're testing, like this:

```
#[cfg(not(test))] 
use log::{info, error}; // Use log crate when building application
#[cfg(test)]
use crate::{info, error}; // Workaround to use prinltn! for logs.
```

Here it is:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! info {
    (target: $target:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => { println!("target: {}, info: {}", $target, $($arg),*) };
    ($($arg:tt)*) => { println!("info: {}", $($arg),*) };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! error {
    (target: $target:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => { printn!("target: {}, info: {}", $target, $($arg),*) };
    ($($arg:tt)*) => { println!("error: {}", $($arg),*) };
}
```

Then I call like this:

```
       error!("Unauthorized message has authentication header but WwwAuthenticate fails to parse. RTSP Message: {:?}", message);
```

but I get:

```
error: expected expression, found `,`
   --> src/rtsp_machine.rs:440:96
    |
440 |                     "Unauthorized message has no AuthenticationInfo header. RTSP Message: {:?}",
    |                                                                                                ^ expected expression
```

Something is wrong with the repetition in the macro argument but I don't know what exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the possibility for your arguments to be separated by commas, hence the *"expected expression, found `,`"* error.

You must also include `format!` as the first argument of the generated `println!` isn't the format chain.

Then, also making the last comma optional with the `$(,)?` part, I can change your macros to this:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! error {
    (target: $target:expr $(,$arg:tt)*) => { println!("target: {}, info: {}", $target, format!($($arg,)*)) };
    ($($arg:tt),*$(,)?) => { println!("error: {}", format!($($arg,)*)) };
}
```

Exemple:

```
fn main() {
    error!(target: "my target" , " thing={:?}", "test");
    error!("bla={} and bit={}", 54, 7);
}
```

would print

```
target: my target, info:  thing="test"
error: bla=54 and bit=7
```